# Getting array with empty values in flask but get correct values in a python notebook

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, flask, logistic-regression

I am making a basic web application which takes the inputs for a logistic regression model and returns the class in which it lies. Here is the code for the prediction:

```
test_data = pd.Series([battery_power, blue, clock_speed, dual_sim, fc, four_g,
             int_memory, m_dep, mobile_wt, n_cores, pc, px_height,
             px_width, ram, sc_h, sc_w, talk_time, three_g,
             touch_screen, wifi])



df = pd.read_csv("Users\ADMIN\Desktop\project\mobiledata_clean.csv")
df.drop(['Unnamed: 0', 'price_range'], inplace=True, axis=1)
print(df)
print(test_data)

#scaling the values
xpred= np.array((test_data-df.min())/(df.max()-df.min())).reshape(1,-1)
print(xpred)
```

the test_data is:

```
0      842
1        0
2      2.2
3        0
4        1
5        0
6        7
7      0.6
8      188
9        2
10       2
11      20
12     756
13    2549
14       9
15       7
16      19
17       0
18       0
19       1
dtype: object
```

Here's the dataframe in df:
[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7n3TB.png)

I get a (1,40) array of null values in the xpred variable. can someone tell me why this is happening

Comment: please show `df`

Comment: @Gulzar i have added an image of the dataframe.

Comment: What is `df.max()-df.min()`?

Comment: @Gulzar It is supposed to give the difference between the max and min values of each column in the dataframe.

Comment: I know. I asked what is the value

Comment: @Gulzar battery_power    1497.0
blue                1.0
clock_speed         2.5
dual_sim            1.0
fc                 19.0
four_g              1.0
int_memory         62.0
m_dep               0.9
mobile_wt         120.0
n_cores             7.0
pc                 20.0
px_height        1959.0
px_width         1498.0
ram              3742.0
sc_h               14.0
sc_w               17.0
talk_time          18.0
three_g             1.0
touch_screen        1.0
wifi                1.0
dtype: float64

Comment: Can't help without running this. Please read [mre] and create a *copy-pasteable* snippet with data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data type of `test_data` is showing as an `object`, try casting it into float and then do the operations maybe.

For series: `s.astype('int64')`
For dataframe: `df.astype({'col1': 'int64'})`